# how to write this code to remove duplication?

Tags: jquery, iframe, upload, code-duplication

I have a file upload, which does a few things but mainly

1. uses iframes to simulate ajax (ajax cant handle file data, at least not cross browser)
2. creates (clones) a new upload input if needed and takes away if not needed
3. allows multiple files to be uploading at the same time (using multiple iframes)

The problem I have, is that at the moment I'm using 4 iframes, but I have had to create 4 iframes, and some lengthy code for each one, even though the code does the same thing, just uses different variable names/ id's etc.

I was hoping someone could help with simplifying my code, if possible to create extra iframes if needed (i.e if more than 4 files are being uploaded at the same time).

the code is fairly lengthy and ive stripped it back to (hopefully) what you guys will need, so HTML:

```
<iframe id="upload_target1" name="upload_target1" class="upload-target" current="current"></iframe>
<iframe id="upload_target2" name="upload_target2" class="upload-target" current="no"></iframe>
<iframe id="upload_target3" name="upload_target3" class="upload-target" current="no"></iframe>
<iframe id="upload_target4" name="upload_target4" class="upload-target" current="no"></iframe>
```

jQuery which handles the form I'm sending through iframe, sets its target iframe and sets up variable used when it returns data:

```
var $fi = $visible.find(".file-info");
        if($('#upload_target1').attr('current') == 'current'){
            $('.file-upload-form').attr('target','upload_target2');
            $('#upload_target1').attr('current','no');
            $('#upload_target2').attr('current','current');
            thisPreview2 = $fi.prev(".image-preview");
        }else if($('#upload_target2').attr('current') == 'current'){
            $('.file-upload-form').attr('target','upload_target3');
            $('#upload_target2').attr('current','no');
            $('#upload_target3').attr('current','current');
            thisPreview3 = $fi.prev(".image-preview");
        }else if($('#upload_target3').attr('current') == 'current'){
            $('.file-upload-form').attr('target','upload_target4');
            $('#upload_target3').attr('current','no');
            $('#upload_target4').attr('current','current');
            thisPreview4 = $fi.prev(".image-preview");
        }else{
            $('.file-upload-form').attr('target','upload_target1');
            $('#upload_target4').attr('current','no');
            $('#upload_target1').attr('current','current');
            thisPreview1 = $fi.prev(".image-preview");
        }
```

jquery which is used on the ioframe load:

```
$('#upload_target1').load(uploadDone1);
$('#upload_target2').load(uploadDone2);
$('#upload_target3').load(uploadDone3);
$('#upload_target4').load(uploadDone4);

function uploadDone1() {
    var returnedValues = $('#upload_target1').contents().find('body').text().split(' ');
    var insertID = returnedValues[0];
    var imgName = returnedValues[1];
    var image =$('<img>').attr('src','images/listing-images/'+imgName);
    $('.insertID-hidden').attr('value',insertID);
    image.appendTo(thisPreview1);
    thisPreview1.css('border','1px solid #ffffff');
    thisPreview1.closest(".file-container").children(".loading").fadeOut(100);
    setTimeout(showUploadedDelete, 200);
    function showUploadedDelete(){
        var uploaded = $('<div>').addClass('file-uploaded');
        uploaded.appendTo(thisPreview1.next());
        thisPreview1.closest(".file-container").children(".file-clear").fadeIn(100);
        thisPreview1.next().children().fadeIn(100);
    }
}

function uploadDone2() {
    (the same as uploadDone1, but uses variable thisPreview2 and upload_target2, and so on upto 4)
}
```

I hope what this shows is that I query whether an iframe has the attribute 'current' set, if it does, then use the next iframe for sending the form, and set up a global variable to be used when the iframe has loaded(thisPreview), but unique to each iframe/ form submit.

As you can see there is a lot of duplicated code, and its limited to however many times I repeat it, whereas I was hoping for an 'unlimited' solution?

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick that you can use is the following:

```
$('#upload_target1').load(uploadDone(1));
$('#upload_target2').load(uploadDone(2));
$('#upload_target3').load(uploadDone(3));
$('#upload_target4').load(uploadDone(4));
```

and then define only one function and concatenate the parameter that you just send (for example at first line of uploadDone function i made a concatenation). Take a closer look and check where do you need more concatenations:

```
function uploadDone(counter) {
    var returnedValues = $('#upload_target'+counter).contents().find('body').text().split(' ');
    var insertID = returnedValues[0];
    var imgName = returnedValues[1];
    var image =$('<img>').attr('src','images/listing-images/'+imgName);
    $('.insertID-hidden').attr('value',insertID);
    image.appendTo(thisPreview1);
    thisPreview1.css('border','1px solid #ffffff');
    thisPreview1.closest(".file-container").children(".loading").fadeOut(100);
    setTimeout(showUploadedDelete, 200);
    function showUploadedDelete(){
        var uploaded = $('<div>').addClass('file-uploaded');
        uploaded.appendTo(thisPreview1.next());
        thisPreview1.closest(".file-container").children(".file-clear").fadeIn(100);
        thisPreview1.next().children().fadeIn(100);
    }
}
```